# Nativescript - trying to run app on device connected to Mac (iOS)

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to run my app on a phone connected directly to the Mac.

tns run iOS

It's in debug mode - not. signed with production certs etc.

I'm getting the following error:

Unable to apply changes on device: 4d86dddfd4ec1ae761441ed5947acb7c143120e3. Error is: Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 65.

I can run on the emulator fine.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Just had that error myself after attaching a new iphone to my computer. 
I did `tns platform remove ios` and then `tns platform add ios` and it worked.

Comment: It was something else - but I'll keep your response in mind next time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue the last week. Exist some zombie processes and some weird ram issues related with that. I can't log everything :(
I did the following:

- Check your current processes in Activity monitor and close everything for the first build.
- Run: `tns build ios --for-device --team-id TEAM_ID`
- After that, run: `tns run ios --team-id TEAM_ID`

Yes, foolish steps but works.

I'll put some logs here when I can.